# swimlane ngx-charts Angular 9, Enable vertical bar chart ability to show and hover over zero (0) values in v11.2.0+ (was available in v11.1.0)

Tags: angular, hover, bar-chart, ngx-charts

It appears that between @swimlane/ngx-charts v11.1.0 and v11.2.0, the ability to display and hover over a vertical bar chart's 0 values was removed. Is it possible to re-enable the ability to see and hover over the bars with a value of 0 in v11.2.0+? (I'm running Angular 9 with ngx-charts v14, but v16 was just released).

Here is the exact same project, with only the ngx-charts version number changed.

[Using ngx-charts v11.1.0](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-chart-v11-1-0-bar-vertical-display-0s?file=package.json)
[image: v11.1.0 allows hover over 0 values]

[Using ngx-charts v11.2.0](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-chart-v11-2-0-bar-vertical-hides-0s?file=package.json)
[image: v12 does not allow for hover or display of 0 values]

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I misunderstood the implications of the added `noBarWhenZero` input flag in v11.2.0 as meaning the bar would not be shown at all (not even on the x axis) but instead the default value is `true`, and needs to be set to `false` if you want to see the bars that have the value of 0 again.

The solution is to set `[noBarWhenZero]="false"` in the chart options.